# can a service contain an activity?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to create a service that has a onWindowFocusChanged method, native to Activity.  but our client has requested the tablet to constantly be looking for such a change in focus  is there a way to add such a listener to a service or have an activity run as part of the service?

Comment: When should this event be fired? The problem needs further explanation.

Comment: If you think you want a service to receive events like this.  All you need to do is follow any tutorial on binding a activity(s) to a service.  This way all your activities in your app may communicate to the service via the listener to you set in the activity. HTH.

Comment: the event needs to fire when ever the focus of the current running application changes..

Comment: problem is i want it to bind to all apps including third party apps on the tablet.. its a hack i know..  client request

Comment: don't understand what's that for.

Comment: binding to all apps (especially one you dont create) just aint happening. Your client may be reaching to far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service does not have `onWindowFocusChanged()` method.

But you can override `onWindowFocusChanged()` in your Base Activity which is parent of all your activities and notify your Service by sending Intent to it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("focus changed");
intent.setClass(this, MyService.class);
startService(intent);
```

You will receive the intent in the service via overriding `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` method.

Comment: Nice approach, but won't work for foreground Services which have no Activities running.